# How to select one row per group in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I'll use nearly the below table and data with the addition of a Net, GST and Gross columns:

```
CustomerPO| Net  | GST |  Gross
DS4284735   100    50     150
DS4284735   70     30     100
```

My expected result will be:

```
CustomerPO| Net  | GST |  Gross
DS4284735   170    80     250
```

How I can achieve this?

my SELECT code is:

```
SELECT dbo.Invoice.CustomerPO AS Reference, dbo.InvoiceDetails.ExtendedPrice AS Net, dbo.InvoiceDetails.TotalTaxes AS GST, 
                     dbo.InvoiceDetails.ExtendedPrice + dbo.InvoiceDetails.TotalTaxes AS Gross
```

Do I have to GROUP BY everything? Note that these two have different InvoiceID's in the database table

Comment: Do you have two tables or one table?

Comment: more than 1 table. :)

Comment: You can join multiple tables to fetch the information. For the columns where you use an aggregate function such as SUM, AVG, etc. you do not have to include those columns in your GROUP BY clause. Any other column that you have in your SELECT clause must appear in your GROUP BY clause. Cetin Basoz has the query you may be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ih.CustomerPO AS Reference, 
   sum(id.ExtendedPrice) AS Net, 
   sum(id.TotalTaxes) AS GST, 
   sum(id.ExtendedPrice + id.TotalTaxes) AS Gross
from dbo.Invoice ih
inner join dbo.InvoiceDetails id on ih.InvoiceId = id.InvoiceId
group by ih.CustomerPO;
```

You would group by the non-aggregate field CustomerPO only.

Comment: this one works! I'll post my query below: Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT dbo.Invoice.CustomerPO AS Reference
, ISNULL(dbo.Invoice.CredInvoiceNo, dbo.Invoice.InvoiceNo)
 AS [Invoice Number]
, AVG(dbo.InvoiceDetails.ExtendedPrice) AS Net
, AVG(dbo.InvoiceDetails.TotalTaxes)  AS GST
, CONVERT(int, ROUND(SUM(dbo.InvoiceDetails.ExtendedPrice + dbo.InvoiceDetails.TotalTaxes), 0)) AS Gross
GROUP BY dbo.Invoice.InvoiceNo, dbo.Invoice.CustomerPO, ISNULL(dbo.Invoice.CredInvoiceNo, dbo.Invoice.InvoiceNo), dbo.Invoice.EntryDate
```